# Learning Promises, Async/Await to control execution order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have been studying promises, await and async functions. While I was just in the stage of learning promises, I realized that the following: When I would send out two requests, there was no guarantee that they would come in the order that they are written in the code. Of course, with routing and packets of a network. When I ran the code below, the requests would resolve in no specific order.

```
const getCountry = async country => {
  await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => err.message);
};

getCountry('portugal');
getCountry('ecuador');
```

At this point, I hadn't learned about async and await. So, the following code works the exact way I want it. Each request, waits until the other one is done.

Is this the most simple way to do it? Are there any redundancies that I could remove? I don't need a ton of alternate examples; unless I am doing something wrong.

```
  await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => err.message);
};

const getCountryData = async function () {
  await getCountry('portugal');
  await getCountry('ecuador');
};

getCountryData();
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should use either `.then`, or `await`, not a mix of both. Apart from that, yes, this is the way.

Comment: Indeed, but why do you need it to come in order? The beauty of JavaScript is its asynchronism, and you should take advantage of it. If you want the data to be in order, after both requests arrived you could sort them; it'd optimize the speed a lot, especially if you ever try to fetch like a thousand countries.

Comment: Each call can be resolved at any time, which is a strength of asynch calls, but if you want to wait and get all of them in a particular order, then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) - as stated in [MDN's documentation about async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#await_and_parallelism)

Comment: Sure, @Rickard Elimää that would've been good approach

Comment: deceze: So, I should have replaced the `.then` with the `await` in the `getCountry` function? BTW...... I apologize for missing some of the code in my second example. But I am sure you all figured it out anyway.

Comment: @code: I just wanted to see if it was possible to come in the order I choose. How could I have sorted them after the data came back?

Comment: In my example, the `getCountry` function should have used just `await` and no `.then` and the exception handling would be the normal `try/catch` block instead of the promise catch block?

Comment: @code Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct way to do so. Do realize though that you're blocking each request so they run one at a time, causing inefficiency. As I mentioned, the beauty of JavaScript is its asynchronism, so take advantage of it. You can run all the requests almost concurrently, causing your requests to speed up drastically. Take this example:

```js
// get results...
const getCountry = async country => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`);
  const json = res.json();
  return json;
};

const getCountryData = async countries => {
  const proms = countries.map(getCountry); // create an array of promises
  const res = await Promise.all(proms); // wait for all promises to complete

  // get the first value from the returned array
  return res.map(r => r[0]);
};

// demo:
getCountryData(['portugal', 'ecuador']).then(console.log);
// it orders by the countries you ordered
getCountryData(['ecuador', 'portugal']).then(console.log);
// get lots of countries with speed
getCountryData(['mexico', 'china', 'france', 'germany', 'ecaudor']).then(console.log);
```

**Edit:** I just realized that `Promise.all` auto-orders the promises for you, so no need to add an extra sort function. Here's the sort fn anyways for reference if you take a different appoach:

```js
myArr.sort((a, b) => 
  (countries.indexOf(a.name.toLowerCase()) > countries.indexOf(b.name.toLowerCase())) ? 1 :
  (countries.indexOf(a.name.toLowerCase()) < countries.indexOf(b.name.toLowerCase()))) ? -1 :
  0
);
```

Comment: Let me see if I follow you here:  the `getCountryData` function maps each country to call the `getCountry` function. The reason you have the `await` before the `fetch` is to make sure the data is available to convert to json then return it. When each item in the array calls `getCountry` it creates an array of promises depending on how many countries we send .  We await for the array of promises to come back. If the promises resolve, now we get the data and return it back from the `getCountryData` function because we know it exists.  But how does the `Promises.all` keep the countries in order?

Comment: How do I loop through this data because each country's data needs to be rendered into HTML. When I print out `console.log` It gives me an array of countries. But how do I use it? I've never seen `console.log` used this way.

Comment: @MattPaolini `.then` takes a callback function, and we specified it as `console.log`, which will invoke `console.log` and pass the result argument to it. You could also do `.then(result => console.log(result))` or just `.then(result => { /*render HTML with the 'result' variable*/ })` (*you can also use a regular instead of arrow function*). I haven't looked at source code for `Promise.all`, but it's likely it implements an array sort function like the one I included in my answer. For promises, you could also use `await` instead of `.then` (only in `async` function).

Comment: I think I understand. `.then(console.log)`  just takes the data from the preceding promise into the `console.log`. You're correct, why use 'await getCountryData('portugal')` We've already waited for `fetch` so our data will be there by the time we need it. This just takes away the concurrency as you mentioned it.  Then, I will use `promise.all` to grab the country data concurrently.  I might not be explaining it well but I understand it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In essence, promises and await make sure we have received the response  resolved or rejected. If resolved, we need to wait for the data to be here until we can start implementing it into the DOM? Asynchronous functions allow us to stop code blocking and do things at the same time. Once we hit the async funtion in our code, we continue on. When the `await` in that function resolves a promise. Right then and there it does something, no matter what other code is running.

Comment: Your `myArray.sort(a, b)` ternary callback is really cool. However, for readability, I would have used something like: 'myArray.sort((a, b) { if (a > b) return 1; if (b < a) return -1; return 0; };` Something like that. Your way is much more elegant. But I prefer something I can understand without digging too deep. I don't know why my code formatting isn't working.

Comment: @MattPaolini okay. Do realize that you shouldn't need to use the sort function as `Promise.all` does it for you.

Comment: I did some research. `Promise.all` takes the array and keeps it in the order that it was sent `array[0], array[1]....` However, if you want to sort them you can just simply do it inline like this, `getCountryData(
  ['ecuador', 'portugal', 'meico', 'costa rica'].sort()
).then(data => loop(data));` Then, it will sort them alphabetically. All of my promises come back resolved, even when the country doesn't exists. Status codes 200, 400 don't return a network error. However, check out the API url with a misspelled country. It comes back as a 200.

Comment: Try [this](https://restcountries.com/v2/name/sssss) The json throws a 404 but there is no way to reach it. Could be a bug in the API. In the console data, it shows a 200.

Comment: I have been studying your code. It makes sense now. The reason it is faster is, when you map the getCountry function, you're not calling it yet (I should have remembered this), all you're doing is supplying the function definition with each country in the array. Then, you actually send them all out at the same time with `promises.all` and wait for the promises to come back as resolved or rejected. When resolved, we now can return the mapped data from the getCountryData function. However, we should probably add a catch after the .then. Is the way I explained it correct?

Comment: In the first example, you're creating callback function definitions with those two countries.  When each promise resolves, the data at position 0 is ready. One country per function execution, returns data for that country because r[0] is the only element in that array.

Comment: I also noticed in developer tools, that all of them start with in .20 seconds of each other. They are sent out in order. The first takes the shortest amount of time and the last one the longest. Makes sense.

Comment: In dev tools, I compared your code with the code I wrote above. My code was running synchronous and yours asynchronous. The waterfall option showed the first call to the function, after that was done, it continued off where the other one end. Your code showed all of the requests running at the same time. Great example I plan on following. Thank you again.

Comment: @MattPaolini great! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it the way @deceze recommended and it works fine: I removed all of the `.then` and replaced them with `await`. A lot cleaner this way. Now I can use normal try and catch blocks.

```
// GET COUNTRIES IN ORDER
const getCountry = async country => {
  try {
    const status = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`);
    const data = await status.json();
    renderCountry(data[0]); // Data is here. Now Render HTML
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.name, err.message);
  }
};

const getCountryData = async function () {
  await getCountry('portugal');
  await getCountry('Ecuador');
};

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  getCountryData();
});
```

Thank you all.